# Ruby class, arguments being passed around methods, instance variable?

Tags: ruby, oop

I'm having this problem which I think it might be a code smell, I have a class that receives an argument in its initialiser and contains one public and several private methods - everything normal. Example:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def apply?(examples)
    foo_1(examples)
  end

  private

  def foo_1(examples)
    foo_2(examples) ? 1 : 2
  end

  def foo_2(examples)
    examples.size > @a
  end
end
```

My problem here, is 'examples' that is received by the public method being carried around over and over the private methods, it doesn't look pretty and it seems like a code smell, what's the best approach here? Make it an instance variable inside the public method?

Thanks

Comment: Query objects violate “Tell Don't Ask” and the return type indicates you're not using “Duck Typing”.  I suggest rethinking the implementation in terms of these for pure OO to help stay out of trouble in the future.

Comment: There's way too little information about the actual requirements and no real-world example use case for this. Normally lack of thereof might be fine for a constructive discussion, but since this is all about good design patterns more information is really required. Otherwise adding examples to initializers and instantiating the class for every query might be a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this may be considered a code smell if the number of private methods accepting `examples` is bigger than 1-2.

One thing to consider would be to extract a class to represent the `rule` here.

For example:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def apply?(examples)
    size_rule_applies?(examples) ? 1 : 2
  end

  private

  def size_rule_applies?(examples)
    SizeRule.new(@a, examples).apply?
  end

  class SizeRule
    def initialize(a, examples)
      @a        = a
      @examples = examples
    end

    def apply?
      @examples.size > @a
    end
  end
end
```

I wouldn't make the `examples` an instance variable of the `Foo` class as there's a risk it would persist in memory between the calls to that object. I've seen bugs like that.

Comment: Since one is creating a new instance of a SizeRule class for every query anyway, why not add `examples` to `Foo`'s initializer?

Comment: You can have one instance of  `Foo` with the `a` always set, but then use this object several times to ask for `apply?` with different `examples` every time. At least, that's how I understand this setup here.

Answer (score 0):

If `examples` changes dynamically then making it instance variable is not an option. You'll either need to instantiate `Foo` for every `examples` or you'll end up having mutable `Foo` where `examples` itself is changing, which is also not good.

Your code looks fine. The only thing that concerns me is that one method depends on another. It's usually not a big deal, but this would look better to me:

```
  def apply?(examples)
    foo_1(examples) && foo_2(examples)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use block:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def apply?(examples)
    foo_1 { examples }
  end

  private

  def foo_1
    v = foo_2 { yield.size }
    v ? 1 : 2
  end

  def foo_2
    yield > @a
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the class `Foo` does nothing else presently than just evaluate `.apply?(examples)` I will advice examples be added to the initializer and  made an instance variable. This is simpler, more efficient and more obvious.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a, examples)
   @a = a
   @examples = examples
  end

  def apply?
    foo_1
  end

  private

  def foo_1
    foo_2 ? 1 : 2
  end

  def foo_2
    @examples.size > @a
  end
end
```